# Fetch second and fourth column from a file

Tags: text-processing, grep

**Problem Statement**

I am not able to get the values in second and fourth column.

**Tried**

```
grep -i "AUGC\|AACN\|AACY" output.csv | cut -d ',' 2,4
```

**DATA**

```
success,1234,["madhu",{'first',[{'last',18}]},"I0","I1",{'MISPswsss',[{'wwwwww',12wqasw}]}]
```

Comment: What's the exact output you're expecting?

Comment: This looks like a partial JSON document. What does the full document look like? If it's JSON, you should be using a JSON parser (like `jq`) and not a line-oriented text manipulation tool.

Comment: please add the output you want

Answer (score 0):

To specify what columns to output, use the `-f` option of `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2,4
```

Your file seems structured, are you sure the expected output for the given line would be the following?

```
1234,{'first'
```

Comment: can you also please tell me how to eliminate ,{ and repplace with  - in output

Comment: @Joshi: You can use sed: `... | sed -e 's/,{/-/'`

Comment: sed: command garbled: s/,[/-/

Comment: @Joshi: You should use copy'n'paste. `{` and `[` are different characters with different meaning.

Comment: of course. So actually i have [ character, also so wanted to replace that. How do i do that, if could just tell that.

Comment: @Joshi: To turn a special character to a literal, backslash it: `s/,\[/-/`

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put given .split(",").[1,3].subst(:global, / <[\[\{\}\]]>+ /);'  file
```

Basically you read the file linewise without autoprinting using the `-ne` flags. If this is a simple-csv type file, `split` on `","` comma, `map` into each resulting element, `subst` all `[{}]` parens and curlies with nothing, then out`put` the correct columns.

Sample Input:

```
success,1234,["madhu",{'first',[{'last',18}]},"I0","I1",{'MISPswsss',[{'wwwwww',12wqasw}]}]
```

Sample Output:

```
1234 'first'
```

https://raku.org